# My Custom Post Type AJAX Query is Returning no posts - why?

Tags: php, posts, ajax, query

When I run this query on posts_type => "posts" it works just fine. But when I add my custom post type 'post_type' => 'case-studies', I get no results.

The custom post type has a custom taxonomy set up of 'case_study_categories'. Can anyone spot what is wrong? I've been looking at this for 3 hours and just don't understand why it isn't working.

**filter-posts.php:**

```
<?php

function ajax_filter_posts_scripts() {
  // Enqueue script
  wp_enqueue_script('afp_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax/filter-posts.js', array('jquery'), null, false);

  wp_localize_script( 'afp_script', 'afp_vars', array(
        'afp_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'afp_nonce' ), // Create nonce which we later will use to verify AJAX request
        'afp_ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
      )
  );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_filter_posts_scripts', 100);

// Script for getting posts
function ajax_filter_get_posts() {

  // Verify nonce
  if( !isset( $_POST['afp_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['afp_nonce'], 'afp_nonce' ) )
    die('Permission denied');

  $data = $_POST['data'];
  $taxonomy = $data['taxonomy'];
  $posts_per_page = $data['posts_per_page'];

    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'case-studies',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
);

  // If taxonomy is not set, remove key from array and get all posts
  if( $taxonomy ) {
    $args['category_name'] = $taxonomy;
  }

  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
  $max = $query->max_num_pages;?>

  <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

    // Used to count the posts and compare to max to hide and show load more button;
    $index = 1;

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
      $index++;
      $featured_img_url_medium = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'medium_large');
      $id = get_the_ID();
      $category = get_the_category();
      $category_name = $category[0]->cat_name;?>
      <a href="<?= get_permalink(); ?>" title="Read - <?php the_title(); ?>" class="dynamic-blogs__card card">
        <div class="news-image-container">
          <div class="hover-read-more">
            <div class="text">
              <i class="fal fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>
              <p>Read Now</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <img class="card-image lazy" src="<?= $featured_img_url_medium; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" loading="lazy">
        </div>

        <div class="card-text-container">
          <?php if( $category_name ) {
            echo '<p class="card-category">' . $category_name . '</p>';
          } ?>
          <?= the_title('<h3 class="">', '</h3>'); ?>
        </div>
      </a><!-- Card END -->

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php if($index <= $max ): ?>
      <div class="dynamic-blogs__load-more py">
        <div class="btn -ghost js-tax-filter" number="12">Load More</div>
      </div>
    <?php endif;  ?>
  <?php else: ?>
    <h2>No posts found</h2>
  <?php endif;

  die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_filter_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts');

?>
```

Comment: The `category_name` parameter is only for Core Categories. You will need to use a Taxonomy Query instead to query by `case_study_categories`.

Comment: @WebElaine that may not be true depending on how it was registered, but it definitely needs to change from `category_name` for non-posts

Comment: Thanks, you were right! I changed it to the below if anyone else gets stuck on this:  `code` 
  if( $taxonomy ) {
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'case_study_categories',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $taxonomy,
        ),
    );
  }